# Which integer types to use for Core Data integers

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data

Core Data has int16, int32, and int64.  When working with these in their NSNumber form should I use NSInteger or int ( and their respective NSNumber methods numberWithInt, numberWithInteger ).  I have been using int for int16 and NSInteger for int32, but I don't know if this is correct.  I would just like some clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSInteger is at least 32 bit, as is int. I wouldn't ever use int16, unless you need to represent a short.

NSInteger can also be 64 bit, in a 64bit runtime...