# In Core Data which attribute type (Integer 16 / 32 / 64) should I use to store small numbers?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I don't know the difference between `Integer 16`, `Integer 32` and `Integer 64`. Which type should I use for storing small numbers, like below 1000?

Comment: More information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765809/core-data-nsnumber-integer-32-and-integer-64 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232826/which-integer-types-to-use-for-core-data-integers

Comment: @Sneak thanks man!